# How to avoid a specific element scroll from getting disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On ipad pro I am trying to disable scroll if popup open and enable the scroll back if popup gets close.
I have found a solution which works perfectly but it blocks inner element scroll too.

```
function preventDefault(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
function disableScroll() {
  document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, { passive: false });
}
function enableScroll() {
  document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault);
}
```

Here, I have an element inside popup which is scrollable and has class name **window-content**. The above solution blocks the scroll for the entire page means it also blocks the scroll for the inner content of popup.
I have tried below code to allow scrolling inside pop but it did not worked.

```
function disableScroll() {
  document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, { passive: false });
  document.getElementsByClassName('window')[0].getElementsByClassName('window-content')[0].removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault);
}
```

I want to allow scroll inside popup and it should only disable for body. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than adding the solution to the question (an oxymoron), you can post an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the preventDefault function to avoid the particular element.

```
preventDefault: function(e) {
    if($(e.target).closest(".k-window").length == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

It is fixed now.